# Scroll bar alway to right when updating highstock graph

Tags: graph, scrollbar, highcharts

I have a graph that is being updated live with AJAX. I get the response and then I use it to update the series and redraw the chart like this:

```
function updateChart() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/get_user_devices_levels",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
      $($chart.series).each(function(i) {
        $chart.series[i].update(response[i]);
      });
      $chart.redraw();
    }
  });
}
```

I want that my scrollbar stays aways in the max of xAxis (right), but when I redraw the chart, it does not go to the right. How can I do it?

Comment: you can use this  https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Deep 3015* suggested: `Axis.setExtremes` can be used for this.

This example shows how to maintain originally selected time interval: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/q2u679zg/

```
    var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0], 
    ex = xAxis.getExtremes(),
    interval = ex.max - ex.min,
    newPoint = [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 5), 7];
    chart.series[0].addPoint(newPoint);
    xAxis.setExtremes(newPoint[0] - interval, newPoint[0]);
```